# Why does this boolean expression return False?

Tags: python

I expect this

print(False == True and not True)

to output `True`, but it outputs `False` instead.

Comment: Why do you think `False and not True` should be `True`? I think you may have mistaken this for `False is not True`.

Comment: its `False and False` it should return False

Comment: If the first argument to `and` is false we don't even need to look at the second one. We already know the final answer is `False`

Comment: The only expression I could find which resembled your description would be: `(False == True) is not True`. I changed the `and` to `is` and I had to put parentheses around the first sub expression.

Comment: It is `(False==True) and (not True)`, which is `False and False`, which is `False`.

Comment: Did you mean `False == (True and not True)`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

code run from left.
see these lines:

```
print(False == (True and not True))
# True
>>> False == True
False
>>> not True
False
print(False == True and not True) # -> print(False and False)
# False
```

Answer (score 3):

The `and` operator just checks for true values in the order you present. So the first time it sees a false, it returns false.

This is because it is evaluating each segment individually. Once it sees a false segment, it doesn't matter what the second segment is as the first is false and `False and True` is false.

Answer (score 1):

You should look at the boolean expression again carefully.

```
False == True # False
not True # False
```

Therefore, both boolean expressions are **False** and so is your **print-statement**

Answer (score 1):

You should write this way for the desired result

```
False == (True and not True)
```